# ASPX image not showing on Firefox

Tags: image, firefox

First of I'm not sure how to formulate this specific question since it's more an browser issue than a coding issue.

I'm trying to get an ASPX image to show inside my `img` tag.

Which seems to work an all other browsers (IE,Chrome, Safari), except Firefox.

Anyone know how?

**Example**

```
<img src="https://example/Download.aspx?Hash=1234" />
```

Comment: does the browser console says some error in your firefox? and do remember to check whether your `content-type` header is set properly or not. dont forget to only send images, no trailing html - sometimes people forgot to `Request.End()` when sending bytes, so asp prints html at the end of the bytes.

Comment: @BagusTesa No errors or warnings

Comment: hit the image directly via the browser, what does it give you? if you could show the code for sending the image, that would be for the best.

Comment: When I try to open the url it says "source file can't be read"

Comment: try to save the file, and see if it an actual image or not. e.g. open it with paint or something.

Comment: I can't save it on Firefox, but I can with other browsers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200230/discussion-between-bagus-tesa-and-salman).